# Can I change my datagridview cell font style based on a condition?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a bounded datagridview and one column is pulling int from the database. Now I am having a hard time telling my grid that when a cell has more than '1' as a value then make it bold.

This is my current code to check on the column. This is on a form load event.

```
DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
            style.Font = new Font(dgvItems.Font.FontFamily,12, FontStyle.Bold);
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvItems.Rows)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(quantityDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Text) > 1)
                {
                    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                        cell.Style.ApplyStyle(style);
                }
            }
```

Comment: _form load_ this is probably too soon. make sure the data are fully loaded before styling the dgv!

Comment: I did that too. I put the code block after inserting the data.

Comment: Well that's from where the styling should be triggered. But in your code, what is `quantityDataGridViewTextBoxColumn`? It is not set in the loop..!?

Comment: That's the `(name)` of the column.

Comment: That makes no sense. If it is the column name then you check the header text? I thought you want to style each cell depending on its value? no? codeninja's code looks correct? have you called it at the right time?

Comment: Just the cells under that column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84657/discussion-between-joshua-masangcay-and-taw).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there are no automatic expressions to do styling of cells in `Winforms DataGridViews`, so you have to do it in code.

You should factor out the styling code and call it each time the data are loaded or have changed.

Here is an example; you may want to change the datatype of the `limit` param and add more params to allow for more complex rules..:

```
void styleCells(DataGridView dgv, string columnName, int limit)
{
    DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
    style.Font = new Font(dgv.Font.FontFamily, 12, FontStyle.Bold);

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
    {

        if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[columnName].Value) > limit)
            row.Cells[columnName].Style.ApplyStyle(style);
    }
}
```

If the column name is indeed `quantityDataGridViewTextBoxColumn` you would call it like this:

```
styleCells(dgvItems, quantityDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, 1);
```

Comment: Still didn't apply it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
style.Font = new Font(dgvItems.Font.FontFamily, 12, FontStyle.Bold);

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvItems.Rows)
{
   foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
   {
      int result;
      bool isInt = Int32.TryParse(cell.Value.ToString(), out result);
      if (isInt && result > 1)
      {
        cell.Style = style;
      }
   }
}
```

--SJ

Comment: Didn't work, unfortunately. I tried placing it on different events though.

Comment: Did u get any exception?

Comment: It didn't. Just didn't apply the  style.

Comment: Can you update your question with entire page load method?